# How can select from same Id's different values?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to make a web page switch pages without loading , but I cannot seem to understand how to verify when a different different value is in my Id:

```
<div id='myId'>home</div>
<div id='myId'>market</div>
```

Want to output it to:

```
<div id="dankMeme"></div>
```

And this is my script:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myId'); 
element.addEventListener('click', () => {
    switch(element.innerHTML) {
    case "market":
        document.getElementById("dankMeme").innerHTML = "you are in the market";
        break;
    case "home":
        document.getElementById("dankMeme").innerHTML = "you are in the home";
        break;
    default:
        // code block
    }
});
```

why does it only work with the first id ?
how can I make it work with all Id's?

Comment: The id attribute should only be used once per page. You want class instead.

Comment: Don't ask how to stop a bullet wound.  Instead, don't shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: It really isn't clear how this code is interacting with the rest of your page. You need to provide a [mcve]. Make it a [inline live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for valid HTML change the ID to Class, you need to loop to add listener to the multiple element

```js
var element = document.querySelectorAll('.myNav')
element.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    switch (item.innerHTML) {
      case "market":
        document.getElementById("dankMeme").innerHTML = "you are in the market";
        break;
      case "home":
        document.getElementById("dankMeme").innerHTML = "you are in the home";
        break;
      default:
        // code block
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<div class='myNav'>home</div>
<div class='myNav'>market</div>
<br>
<div id="dankMeme"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

The id value can be used by CSS and JavaScript to perform certain tasks for the element with the specific id value.

In CSS, to select an element with a specific id, write a hash (#) character, followed by the id of the element

Comment: It doesn't work with classes either >.< this is so frustrating